# Skype4java Onlinestauslistener

Tags: skype4java

We are using skype4java plugin in our application to send the messages and calls through our application in java.

```
We are able to get the chatListener(......) to find, when msg send and when received.
```

Our requirement is we are get the status of the user when user change his state(offline,online,dad,..). I didnt find any listener for this in skype.

how we acheive this.  please sugguest on this.

Thanks,

C.Govindarajulu

Answer (score 1):

You may add a `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener` via `com.skype.User.addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener)` for each instance of a User you are interested in receiving status events.